# Why are < or > required to use /dev/tcp

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection, devices

When trying to call `/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80`, by typing

```
/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
```

Bash says `no such file or directory`. When looking at other people's code online, they use syntax such as

```
 3<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
```

I noticed that this works as well:

`</dev/tcp/www.google.com/80`

Why are these symbols required to call certain things in bash?

Comment: What do you mean by “call”? Please show us what you are doing, when you get the error. Are you trying to execute it? Even if the front page of google was executable code, I would not recommend it.

Comment: /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80

Comment: I edited your question, to say what I thing you mean.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Because that's a feature of the shell (of ksh, copied by bash), and the shell only.

`/dev/tcp/...` are not real files, the shell intercepts the attempts to redirect to a `/dev/tcp/...` file and then does a `socket(...);connect(...)` (makes a TCP connection) instead of a `open("/dev/tcp/..."...)` (opening that file) in that case.

Note that it has to be spelled like that. `cat < /dev/./tcp/...` or `///dev/tcp/...` won't work, and will attempt to open those files instead (which on most systems don't exist and you'll get an error).

The direction of the redirection also doesn't matter. Whether you use `3< /dev/tcp/...` or `3> /dev/tcp/...` or `3<> /dev/tcp/...` or even `3>> /dev/tcp/...` won't make any difference, you'll be able to both read and write from/to that file descriptor to receive/send data over that TCP socket.

When you do `cat /dev/tcp/...`, that doesn't work because `cat` doesn't implement that same special handling, it does a `open("/dev/tcp/...")` like for every file (except `-`), only the shell (ksh, bash only) does, and only for the target of redirections.

That `cat -` is another example of a file path handled specially, this time, by `cat`, not the shell.

Instead of doing a `open("-")` and reading the input from the resulting file descriptor, `cat` reads directly from the file descriptor 0 (stdin). `cat` and many text utilities do that, the shell doesn't for its redirections. To read the content of the `-` file, you need `cat ./-`, or `cat < -` (or `cat - < -`). On systems that don't a have `/dev/stdin`, `bash` will however do something similar for redirections from that (virtual) file. GNU `awk` does the same for `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/stderr` even on systems that do have such files which can cause some surprises on systems like Linux where those files behave differently.

`zsh` also has TCP (and Unix domain stream) socket support, but that's done with a `ztcp` (and `zsocket`) builtins, so it's less limited than the ksh/bash approach. In particular, it can also act as a server which ksh/bash can't do. It's still much more limited than what you can do in a real programming language though.

Answer (score 13):

You seem to be confusing the ideas or reading a file and executing a command. The difference between data and instruction.

Googles front page is not an executable program. And if it was, it would not be safe to run it.

The redirection characters (including `<` and `>`), are used to direct data into a command.

We could do `cat < /dev/tcp/towel.blinkenlights.nl/23` However this won't work for `/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80` as this port will not respond until we send `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`

So try

```
{
  printf >&3 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
  cat <&3
} 3<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
```

Comment: You would get a different error if the file exists but isn't executable.